# How to reverse a 2-dimension table into 1 dimension list in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am looking in Tableau for a tip that  reverse a 2-dimension table into 1 dimension list.
I usually leverage Excel function to do it, but I believe that there is a smart Tableau way to do it.

**Step**

[image: The steps of "2-dimension table into 1 dimension list"]

Excel Detail:
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2461-excel-reverse-pivot-table.html

Comment: Are you asking about this[Tableau Excel add-in](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/addin-reshaping-data-excel)?

Answer (score 2):

Tableau makes a tool for reshaping Excel files. Here's the Knowledge Base article.

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/addin-reshaping-data-excel

Comment: Also, starting in version 9.0, there is support for doing some reshaping directly in Tableau